# VBA return index of a cell containing a particular string

Tags: excel, vba, search

I have two columns with text data.

All I want to do is search the first column "J" for a specific string and return the value of the same row on column "H".

I know all I need to do is find the cell index in column J and return the offset value for column H.

What is the syntax for this?

Comment: You dont remember the remember word !

Comment: Word?? In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. ?? that word ? ;)

Comment: check out your first line and see the remember word how you have typed!

Comment: I did not edit it so that you dont do that mistakes again and again'

Comment: Dyslexix that is a word I have been mestaking all my life,although thats a new version.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an Index and Match combination.  Here's a couple of links:

http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/excel-vlookup-index-match.php

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214142

Comment: Thats the one I was looking for !! thank you the very same page from before. must add to libuary this time.